# Mayer-Vietoris sequence for orbifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, group-cohomology, stacks, orbifolds

Is there a version of the Mayer-Vietoris long exact sequence for orbifolds? I am interested in orbifold homology as opposed to the homology of the underlying topological space.

Comment: Can you give a reference defining orbifold homology?

Comment: Is this what you had a in mind for a definition of orbifold homology? http://www.math.colostate.edu/~renzo/teaching/Orbifolds/Ruan.pdf On page 35, the authors mention that a Mayer-Vietoris argument can be extended to their setting.

Comment: By orbifold homology, I mean view the orbifold as a stack and take the homology of the homotopy type of the stack. For example, the orbifold homology of a point mod G is the group homology of G. 1.3.1 (iv) of http://arxiv.org/pdf/q-alg/9708021.pdf seems to indicate that Mayer-Vietoris holds.